# Meteor.user() not fully loaded after login

Tags: meteor, field, accounts

I am using Meteor 0.8.2 with accounts-facebook. I set up a limited publication for the users this way:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {'profile.picture': 1, 'profile.gender':1, 'profile.type':1}, sort: {'profile.likes': -1}});
});
```

Now this works great: when I requests a user list from the client I get a list of all users, with the current user's fields all shown and only the 3 published fields for the others. **Except:** right after login.

When I login and type `Meteor.user()`, here is what I get:

```
_id: "uACx6sTiHSc4j4khk"
profile: Object { gender="male", type="1", picture="http://....jpg"}
```

This stays like that until I refresh the page using the browser button. After refreshing, `Meteor.user()` gives all the fields available, while `Meteor.users.find()` still gives the correct restrictions. (except for the current user of course)

Why does my current user not get all its fields right away? I read about a `Meteor.userLoaded()` method used to wait for the user to be loaded, but it seems to be obsolete in the latest version.

Comment: What other fields do you expect to see on the current user? You may also be running into a known restriction where only top-level fields are merged properly over a publish function; see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/998.

Comment: Well... `profile.likes`, for example. As you can see I don't publish this field, only do a sorting on it before publishing. So when I first login, the current user doesn't show `profile.likes`, but after I refresh the page, poof, it contains everything a user request gives on the server side. (as well it should, since it's the current user) Includind `profile.likes` of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew explained, and as I kinda thought, what happened is that there is another "hidden" publication for the current user, which conflicts with mine. All I had to do in order to fix this was to simply exclude the current user from my publication, since it is already fully published by default:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id:{$ne: this.userId}}, {fields: {'profile.picture': 1, 'profile.gender':1, 'profile.type':1}, sort: {'profile.likes': -1}});
});
```

This simple $ne does it for me.

Answer (score 5):

You're running into an interaction between the restriction of merging fields across publications, and the default user publication which sends the `profile` field.

First, note that there is a built-in publication that always sends the currently logged in user's entire `profile` field to that user:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L1172

Second, merging of fields at more than one level deep is currently not supported:

> https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/998

What you currently have is an issue where the default publication is sending something like the following

```
{
  username: ...,
  emails: [ ... ],
  profile: { 
    ... all fields ... 
  }
}
```

whereas the publication you have set up is sending

```
{
  profile: {
    picture: ...
    gender: ...
    type: ...
  }
}
```

These get merged on the client according to the rules for how subscriptions are resolved (http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe). In particular, see the last paragraph. Meteor knows to merge the `username` and `email` fields with the `profile` field. However, it doesn't do this merging at the inner level. So one of the `profile` fields will get chosen arbitrarily to show up in the client's collection. If the first one wins, you will see `profile.likes`. If the second one wins, you won't.

It's likely that this behavior is somewhat deterministic and changes depending on whether a normal login handler is called or a resume handler (i.e. when reloading the browser). Hence why it looks like it hasn't loaded.

Comment: Thank you for this. So if I were to put my needed fields "outside" of the profile subset, it is more likely to work?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "more likely". You should either publish all the profile fields or none of them. And you can definitely put other fields in other sub-documents, but note that the `profile` field is special because it is client-editable by default.

Comment: Hm... somehow I cannot retrieve my "likes" count when it's outside of `profile`. I think that is why I had put it in there in the first place.

Comment: Well, you'll need to publish whatever field it is stored in. It seems like you were relying on the default publish behavior. Likes shouldn't be stored in profile because they shouldn't be editable anyway.

Comment: Okay I think I fixed it ;) thanks a lot for your help, will document in a sec